# plone 4 new style collection filtering with "and" operator

Tags: plone

I have been trying to use the new collection in plone 4.2.1 to filter a set of documents. I can not use the 'and' operator to get the result I need.

For example I have the following documents:

- document1, tag 'yellow'
- document2, tag 'yellow', 'red'
- document3, tag 'red'

How do I filter the collection to show only document 2?

Comment: disable new style collection and use previous one, which works, does not have major bugs, and can do a lot of things.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. I was trying to avoid going backwards, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with the new-style-collections, because of the missing and/or-operators. :(

Comment: Thanks, Ida. I am wondering if there is a plan to fix this shortcoming in the future.

Comment: AFAIK, it's on the "to do" list.  I don't think there is an ETA.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible (the way you want), but I have made a (very ugly) hack (which also has some minor bugs (basically if the tag contains spaces) in collective.ptg.quicksand

1) the tags are added to the content as (css) classes

2) A javascript (or css file) hides those without the right class.

This would mean that document1 has 'div class"yellow"' and document2 has 
div class="yellow red". Then you hide all the divs with css (or javascript) and shows document2 by

.red.yellow {display: block} or similar.

You can see the idea here :http://products.medialog.no/galleries/quicksand
(although here I have not made any tags containing both (red and yellow), but that should be just to remove the "split" in the init py file, line 82 here:

init.py">https://github.com/collective/collective.ptg.quicksand/blob/master/collective/ptg/quicksand/**init**.py